# How do I get only Tables and only views? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Context: The above query lists all the tables and views. How do I list only tables? How do I list only views?

Comment: From the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you add ` where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'` to your query. Always check the docs before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sys.tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
USE <database_name>;  
GO  
SELECT name FROM sys.tables
```

You can also use [sys.objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with filter for type ='U' -- corresponding to user defined tables

```
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'
```

To List only views:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;

USE <database_name>;  
GO
SELECT name from SYS.views

SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'V'
```

Comment: Hi Venkataraman, can you please improve the answer by adding the query to list only views also?